# fs.readFile is failed to read thumbnail generated file using ffmpeg in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, readfile, fs

I am using ffmpeg to extract the screenshot from the video it is working as expected but that file is unable to read/buffer using fs.read, later I will have to upload the image to the s3 bucket, So who can I make the file readable?

```
var thumPath =  path.join(global.__base, 'Temp/');
    ffmpeg(req.file.path).screenshots({
            count: 1,
            filename: req.file.filename + 'thumbnail-at-%s-seconds.png',
            folder: thumPath,
            size: '320x240'
        });

       fs.readFile(thumPath + req.file.filename + 'thumbnail-at-%s-seconds.png', function(err, thumb) {
          console.log(thumb) 
//s3 bucket feature will come
       })
```

Comment: What is the error message when you try to read the image?

Comment: @RemisaYousefvand No errors, but `console.log(thumb) ` returns undefined

Comment: I guess `ffmpeg` returns a promise and you don't wait for it to complete the operation so next line (fs.readFile) is executed before thumbnails are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Reading documentation for `https://github.com/damianociarla/node-ffmpeg` the function requires callback, which is executed AFTER ffmpeg stops working (error or correct), only then the file can be checked.

What you do now is:

- Tell ffmpeg to create the tumbnail
- Ask if the thumbnail file exists
- .... (node will wait as there is still something doing there)
- ffmpeg finished his work
- node completes.